# Eternal Ajax Returns Nothing, No PHP/Javascript errors, syntax or otherwise

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Note: I am aware that json/jquery appears to be the preferred way of doing things at the moment. Nevertheless, I am using just plain old ajax without json/jquery.

I have set my website up so that there are no php calls in the index page. Instead, I load scripts which handle most link clicks via ajax calls back to the server. Theoretically, the server returns the response text, and then the javascript on readystatechange function (set to ajax_response()) inserts the response text directly into the div container with id="innercontent".

Here is the code for my main javascript file:

```
function ajax()
{
    try{ var request = new XMLHttpRequest()}
    catch(e1){
    try{ request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP") }
    catch(e2){
        try{ request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") }
        catch(e3){ request = false }
        }
    } return request
}

function ajax_response()
{
    if(this.readyState == 4){
    if(this.status == 200){
        if(this.responseText != null){
        document.getElementById('innercontent').innerHTML = this.responseText
            } else alert("Ajax error: No data received")
        } else alert("Ajax error: " + this.statusText)
    }
}

function fetch_document(opcode)
{
    params = "opcode=" + opcode
    request = new ajax();

    request.open("POST", "/site-php/fetch_document.php", true)
    // request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    // request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length)
    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")

    request.onreadystatechange = ajax_response()
    request.send(params)
}

function fetch_comic(series, page_number)
{
    params = "series=" + series + "&page_number=" + page_number
    request = new ajax();

    request.open("POST", "/site-php/fetch_comic.php", true)
    // request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    // request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length)
    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")

    request.onreadystatechange = ajax_response()
    request.send(params)
}
```

There doesn't appear to be any syntax errors in the javascript, so I thought maybe that the problem was on the server side. But no errors are logged in `/var/log/error_log`.

Here is the code for my php functions:

```
<?php

require_once "kolodruid.php";
require_once "login.php";


if(isset($_POST['series']) && isset($_POST['page_number'])){
  $series = $_POST['series'];
  $page_number = $_POST['page_number'];
}

$mysql_db = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
mysql_select_db("webcomics");
mysql_close($mysql_db);

$fd = $docroot . "test.html";
$msg = file_get_contents($fd);

echo $msg;

?>
```

Note that the actual functionality of this function is to fetch webcomic information from a database. In the process of trying to figure out what has gone wrong, however, I ended up simplifying the function to try to see if just a simple echo statement would work.

also:

```
<?php

require_once "kolodruid.php";
$opcode = $_POST['opcode'];

switch($opcode){
case "ABOUT":
  echo file_get_contents("about.html");
  break;
default:
  echo file_get_contents("whoops.html");
  break;
}

?>
```

When I look at the firefox console network tab, clicking on the links "webcomic" generates green lights all the way. I check to see if the parameters tab has any data, and it does. The response tab, however, doesn't contain anything.

I've checked that all the files are reachable and in places that the server has access to. I also took out the setrequestheader() functions in the javascript, as it seems that was causing a fatal error. I then re-enabld the close connection setrequestheader() to see if maybe I actually still had to set that one manually. It seems that it didn't generate a fatal error, so I didn't comment it back out.

I've checked the php code for syntax errors, and also checked the javascript code for syntax errors. Both come out clean. I've restarted my server several times (it's localhost), and have also restarted my mysql database server out of desperation.

At this point, the whole enterprise had devolved into just making minor edits in the desperate hope that SOMETHING gives a clue as to what is going on. I have changed the asynchronous calls to synchronous calls to see if that maybe was the problem, but to no avail. (Thus, I rechanged them back to asynchronous calls).

I feel like it's something really stupid and/or obvious, but I've been pouring over the code for hours, and am afraid I can't see the forest for the trees by now. Please help!

Thank you for reading this. I'm aware that Javascript questions are pretty common, but I've been reading question and answer sites for hours, too. D:

In case it matters, I'm using Apache version 2.4.6
Thank you for you help!

Comment: Sniff network, and try to use jQuery instead of plain js everywhere, also try to open your php script as is in browser

Comment: For starters, `request.onreadystatechange = ajax_response()` *calls* the function immediately and assigns the *result* to the `onreadystatechange` property. That's not what you want. (Also, lint your code, you seem to be using global variables everywhere.)

Comment: Oh... for the love of god... that fixed it. It was mindblowingly obvious, DCoder. I feel embarassed now, albeit very happy. :D Thank you very much, DCoder. I'll give you some reputation for sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be something mind-blowingly obvious after all. I was calling the function `ajax_response()` and assigning the value to `onreadystatechange`. Removing the parenthesis after `ajax_response` produced the desired behavior.